# Formatting issue in header of DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am trying to add some additional elements to the header of my datatables grid and all is working except the Search box is bumped down one row. How can I center the radio buttons, and get the search box to show up on the same row as the rest? Does it have something to do with the <"Clear">?

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var tbl = $('#EACApprovalGrid').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Search:",
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "bStateSave": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aaSorting": [[5, "asc"]],
        "sDom": '<"top"l<"EacEcrRadioRegion">f>rt<"bottom"p<"clear">>'
    });


    var btns = '<input type="radio" class="EacEcrSelection" name="EacEcrSelection" id="EacRadio" value="EAC" /> EAC&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
            + '<input type="radio" class="EacEcrSelection" name="EacEcrSelection" id="EcrRadio" value="ECR" /> ECR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
            + '<input type="radio" class="EacEcrSelection" name="EacEcrSelection" id="BothRadio" value="Both" /> Both'
    $(".EacEcrRadioRegion").html(btns);


    $('#EacRadio').click(function() {tbl.fnFilter("EAC",0);});
    $('#EcrRadio').click(function() {tbl.fnFilter("ECR",0);});
    $('#BothRadio').click(function() {tbl.fnFilter("",0);});

});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7KkpQ/3/

And here's a screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4Wry.jpg
  (before you ask - yes, it happens in IE, FF, and Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

This could be very close:
http://jsfiddle.net/7KkpQ/9/

extra CSS follows:

```
.EacEcrRadioRegion {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#example_filter {   
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: This is strange.  That fixes it in the fiddle, but makes it worse on my real site.  I can't post a link because it's a private site, but here is a link to some screen shots.
http://imgur.com/1N6ABtP

Comment: I know it might sound silly, but try clear browser cache and reload page. It helped me numerous times.